# Nested property delegation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-delegate

As mentioned in the official tutorial, we can [store properties in a Map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) and delegate a class to it:

```
class User(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
    val name: String by map
    val age: Int     by map
}
```

However, sometimes we store non-trivial structures in a map, like another class (this is usual when working with complicated jsons). To better elaborate my idea, I came up with a pseudo-code like this:

```
class User(val map: Map<String, Any?>) {
    val name: String by map
    val otherType: OtherType by map
}

class OtherType {}
```

Is it possible to delegate such nested structure?

Comment: Why did you not test it yourself before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem, you can do this. It works:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val user = User(mapOf("name" to OtherType(1)))
    println(user)
}

data class User(val map: Map<String?, Any?>) {
    val name: String by map
    val otherType: OtherType by map
}

data class OtherType(val something:Int) {}
```

You can delegate any type you want.